# Turn off safe search in a DuckDuckGo Image Search API

Tags: python

I'm using [a DuckDuckGo Image Search API](https://github.com/joeyism/duckduckgo-images-api) as a discord bot command to send image URLs to a text channel.

I want to turn safe search off but seems like it's always on 'Moderate' mode.

I've tried setting `'p'` and `'kp'` to `-2` in the `params` and in the DuckDuckGo URL but no changes to the image results.

Thank you for your time.

```
async def imgSearch(ctx, keywords:str, safe='1', maxImgs:int=3):
  url = 'https://duckduckgo.com/'

  params = {
    'q': keywords,
    'p': safe,
    'kp': safe,
  }

  res = requests.post(url, data=params)
  searchObj = re.search(r'vqd=([\d-]+)\&', res.text, re.M|re.I)

  if not searchObj:
    return -1

  headers = {
    'authority': 'duckduckgo.com',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */* q=0.01',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'referer': 'https://duckduckgo.com/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,enq=0.9',
  }

  params = (
    ('l', 'us-en'),
    ('o', 'json'),
    ('q', keywords),
    ('vqd', searchObj.group(1)),
    ('f', ',,,'),
    ('p', safe),
    ('kp', safe),
    ('v7exp', 'a'),
  )

  requestUrl = url + "i.js"

  for i in range(maxImgs):
    while True:
      try:
        res = requests.get(requestUrl, headers=headers, params=params)
        data = json.loads(res.text)
        break
      except ValueError as e:
        continue
    
    for r in data["results"]:
      await ctx.send(r["image"])
      break

    if "next" not in data:
      return 0

    requestUrl = url + data["next"]

#run the function
await imgSearch(channel, query, '-2', 2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I've tried setting 'p' and 'kp' to -2 in the params" Okay, but this function makes two API calls, with separate `params`. Did you try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the results, for example by checking the `res.text` from the first request? What information did this give you? How about from the second request? Specifically why do you believe that the setting isn't taking effect? Specifically what result do you expect to get, that differs from the results you are actually getting?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and help make it easy for others to understand the problem.

Comment: (Also, I removed the `discord.py` tag because this question doesn't appear to actually involve the Discord API; the code shows an attempt to call the function manually, so clearly the problem still occurs even when not using Discord or attempting to run a bot.)

Comment: I'm expecting the same results on normal browser with safe search off when searching for an explicit content to show up via the discord command. 
In the discord command, I've tried setting the `kp` in the `params` as `-2` but the results I get are as if I set the safe search setting on 'Moderate' in the DuckDuckGo search settings.
If I add `&kp=-2` in the DuckDuckGo URL on a normal browser, it'll turn safe search off but I have no idea why it's not doing the same thing in the discord command.

Comment: I'm not clear on how the link relates to your code. It doesn't appear that you're *using* that library, but instead taking inspiration from it? I'm not sure where you got the `kp` parameter idea from, because I don't see it in the Github code. Did you mean to link to actual API documentation instead? Or is that, for example, your own committed and pushed work that you're now trying to improve upon?

Comment: You might also find [this](https://api.duckduckgo.com/api) useful.

Comment: At first, I imported the library and used it like in the usage example.
I want to turn safe search off but it's not mentioned on the Github and I don't know how so I thought it might be related to `kp` so I took the code from Github and rewrote it a bit without importing the library anymore.
I only want a way to turn safe search off and get explicit results to show up.